# Change set components needed for Path?

Tags: change-set, pathassistant

What components do I need to move from one org to another to get a path component working on a lightning record page again? I'm using a change set to move the components.  I'm currently getting this error:

"Error on loading Path
You cannot view this Path. Contact your Salesforce administrator for help."

I've moved the

1. Lightning record page
2. Path Assistant
3. Stage field (stage pick list items changed since sandbox creation)

I've looked for info on this error, but haven't found anything that applies to my situation.  There's this post on the success community:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iVtDQAU

but I doubt it applies since the path is working in production.

Background: Path component got deleted from record page in sandbox (and maybe just plain deleted as well).  Hoping to

I could refresh the sandbox after backing up a few things, but I'd like to understand what is happening here.  After all, I might have to move a record page and path to production some day.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. The reason that my specific user had this error was because their profile didn't have the read permission for all the fields that I have used on the Path. Once I added the read permission it was visible again.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I also needed to put the following in the change set:

Record Type
Page Layout

The Stage field was recently added to the instance and had not been put in a record type or a page layout at the time the sandbox was created.